# How to increase the font size of the body in tikzposter?

Tags: tikzposter

currently, the maximum is 25 pt. I would like to make it bigger than that.

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, consider adding an MWE to help you sufficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 \documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
     blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter} %Default values for poster format options.

 \tikzposterlatexaffectionproofon %shows small comment on how the poster was made at bottom of poster
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
 % Commands
 \newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}   % backslash
 \newcommand{\cmd}[1]{{\bf \color{red}#1}}   % highlights command

 % Title, Author, Institute
 \title{Using tikzposter}
 \author{Pascal Richter, Elena Botoeva, Richard Barnard, \& Dirk Surmann}
 \institute{}

 % -- PREDEFINED THEMES ---------------------- %
 % Choose LAYOUT:  Default, Basic, Rays, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, Desert,
 \usetheme{Autumn}
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}


 \begin{document}

     \maketitle
         \block[roundedcorners=40]{Creating the document}{
             The document begins with:
             You can use `anyfontsize` package along with `fontsize`.\\

             The two arguments to `fontsize\{actual font size\}\{the size of the baseline-skip\}`.\\

             {\fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont Foo}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont bar!}\\

             {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Foo}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont bar!}\\

             {\Huge Foo}{\tiny bar!}\\

             base-line skip $\approx 1.2\times$ font-size.


 \innerblock[]{Inner Blocks}{Inner blocks may be created inside of blocks with the command \bs\texttt{innerblock[{\it options}]\{{\it Heading}\}\{{\it Text}\}} }
            \coloredbox{Text may be highlighted using colored boxes created by \bs\texttt{coloredbox[{\it options}]\{{\it Text\}}}}

     }


 \end{document}
%%
%% End of file `tikzposter-example.tex'.
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. it worked.